# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and Vue.js 2 to save some information along with file(video) in DB.But i got error like this

error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjN5a.jpgPUT

```
http://localhost:8000/videos/null 404 (Not Found)
```

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131:
No query results for model [App\Models\Video].
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){

    Route::get('/upload','VideoUploadController@index');
    Route::post('/videos','VideoController@store');
    Route::put('/videos/{video}','VideoController@update');


    Route::get('/channel/{channel}/edit','ChannelSettingsController@edit');
    Route::put('/channel/{channel}/edit','ChannelSettingsController@update');

});
```

Controler:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\VideoUpdateRequest;
use App\Models\Video;
class VideoController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = uniqid(true);

        $channel = $request->user()->channel()->first(); 

        $video = $channel->video()->create([

            'uid'=>$uid,
            'title'=>$request->title,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'visibility'=>$request->visibility,
            'video_filename'=>"{$uid}.{$request->extension}",
            ]);
        return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                'uid' => $uid
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function update(VideoUpdateRequest $request, Video $video)
    {

     //authentication checked here .......


        $video->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'visibility' => $request->visibility,
            'allow_votes' => $request->has('allow_votes'),
            'allow_comments' => $request->has('allow_comments')
        ]);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(null, 200);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Uplod.vue

```
 <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <input type="file" name="video" id="video" @change="changfileInputChange" v-if="!uploading">
                           <div id="video-form" v-if="uploading&&!failed">

                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title">Title</label>
                                <input type="" name="" v-model="title" class="form-control">

                           </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control"v-model="description"></textarea>

                           </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="visibility">Visibility</label>
                                <select class="form-control" v-model="visibility">
                                    <option value="private">Private</option>
                                    <option value="public">Public</option>
                                    <option value="unlisted">Unlisted</option>
                                </select>

                           </div>
                               <span class="help-block pull-right">{{saveStatus}}</span>
                             <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"@click.prevent="update">Save changes</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        data()
        {
            return{
                uid:null,
                uploading:false,
                uplodComplete:false,
                failed:false,
                title:'unlisted',
                description:null,
                visibility:'private',
                saveStatus:null
            }

        },

        methods:{
            changfileInputChange()
            {
                this.uploading=true;
                this.failed=false;
                this.file=document.getElementById('video').files[0];

                this.storeVideo().then(()=>{

                })
            },

            storeVideo(){
                return this.$http.post('/videos',{
                    title:this.title,
                    description:this.description,
                    visibility:this.visibility,
                    extension:this.file.name.split('.').pop()

                }).then((response)=>{
                    this.uid = response.json().data.uid;
                });
            },
            update() {
                this.saveStatus = 'Saving changes.';

                return this.$http.put('/videos/' + this.uid, {
                    title: this.title,
                    description: this.description,
                    visibility: this.visibility
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.saveStatus = 'Changes saved.';

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.saveStatus = null
                    }, 3000)
                }, () => {
                    this.saveStatus = 'Failed to save changes.';
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In first i save video to db along with some default value for title,description etc with ajax request,Please see Video.vue code for this

I am getting `uid`(unique id for video)in console from store method but when i update by clicking the save chages button i got error like this:

when i used i default `uid` in controller in

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uid = '158cfff622e1b7';

       //....some code here
    //finally return $uid
return response()->json([
            'data' => [
                'uid' => $uid
            ]
        ]);
}
```

and in `Upload.vue`in this line if i change `uid` to default `158cfff622e1b7`,it works fine ie:result updated

```
return this.$http.put('/videos/' +'158cfff622e1b7', {
//code

});
    it means i am not getting `uid` ,or something is wrong,please help me
```

Here is screenshot of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjN5a.jpg

Error: `PUT http://localhost:8000/videos/null 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using route model binding.

```
Route::put('/videos/{video}','VideoController@update');
```

Route model binding works out of the box with `ID` field. If you use a different key, you need to tell your model to use that key for route model binding.

In Video model add

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'uid';
}
```

**Update**

In providers/RouteServiceProvider, add this inside `boot()`

```
Route::bind('video', function ($value) {
    return App\Models\Video::where('uid', $value)->first();
});
```

If it still does not work, simply get the video and update it, the good old way

```
public function update(VideoUpdateRequest $request, $uid)
{
    $video = Video::where('uid', $uid)->first();
    $video->title = $request->title;
    $video->description = $request->description;
    ...
    $video->update();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(null, 200);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: i have wriiten that in video model

Comment: public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'uid';
    }

Comment: Check my updates. To make sure your route model binding works, try to simply get a video. Nothing else. Just getting the video

Comment: iam getting this:  No query results for model [App\Models\Video].

Comment: You can try to do it the old way as I just did. If you really want it to wok. But if you have to make it through route model binding, then all good.

Comment: TheDove update is not the problem.problem is that i am not getting response uid from js after video inserted. this line in above code: this.uid = response.json().data.uid;

Comment: Console.log your response at let me see. `console.log(response)`;

Comment: it says :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Replace this  `this.uid = response.json().data.uid;` by  `this.uid = response.body.data.uid;`

it must work,if not let me hear

Read [Docs](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#response) for more

Comment: Thank you @ Ranjit Karki, it working now.Thank you so much